# Installing Ubuntu - No options in Boot Device Priority list

Tags: boot, partitioning, uefi

sorry if my English is bad and I have to post a screenshot in Italian, but for some reason, Ubuntu Italy, site and forums are down. At least for a good chunk of the users.
I'm trying to **install ubuntu via USB pen on my new laptop**. I know that I have to change the boot device priority to make Ubuntu run, so I go to Bios with F2 but I find something never seen before.
[image: Old screenshot, currently the Secure Boot is disabled]
As you can see, there's **just an item on the list**: Windows Boot Manager.
I set a supervisor password and I entered it, disabled the Secure Boot, but even after a restart, other options in the Boot Priority Order are still absent.
Is it a matter of Security settings or is my laptop doomed?
[image: Here my security settings]
Relevant informations(?): My laptop runs both on SSD and HDD. Here the properties.
Acer Aspire 3
AMD Ryzen 2500u
AMD Radeon Vega Mobile Graphics
8GB DDR4 Memory
256 GB SSD, 1000 GB HDD